# Numpy array multiple mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Trying to slice and average a numpy array multiple times, based on an integer mask array:

i.e.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(11)
mask = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])

results = list()
for maskid in range(1,4):
    result = np.average(data[mask==maskid])
    results.append(result)
output = np.array(result)
```

Is there a way to do this faster, aka without the "for" loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
np.bincount(mask, data)/np.bincount(mask)
```

Another one with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for a generic case when the elements in `mask` aren't necessarily sequential starting from `0` -

```
_,ids, count = np.unique(mask, return_inverse=1, return_counts=1)
out = np.bincount(ids, data)/count
```